# Google APIs Client Library for PHP and Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

Could someone explain how in install the [Google APIs Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/README.md#installation) in Codeigniter 3 please? I am not using composer.

I have downloaded a zip file (google-api-php-client-2.1.1), but I'm unsure where to unzip it and include it in Codeigniter.

The documentation states;

> Uncompress the zip file you download, and include the autoloader in
>   your project:
>
> require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this in application/vendor/google/google-api-php-client/vendor
and require like

```
require APPPATH . 'vendor/google/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
```

edit: require it in your controller where you need it (or model, depends on your setup)